# Scrollview ContentSize

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to make a scrollview with 3 pictures on a sign up/join page for a small app I trying to make. I was using this code below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var signInButton: UIButton!
    var joinButton: UIButton!
    var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var colors:[UIColor] = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.yellowColor()]
    var frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        signInButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(1/3.0 * self.view.bounds.size.width, 5/6.0 * self.view.bounds.size.height, 23, 60))

        joinButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(2/3.0 * self.view.bounds.size.width, 5/6.0 * self.view.bounds.size.height, 23, 60))

        pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRectMake(1/2.0 * self.view.bounds.size.width, 70/100.0 * self.view.bounds.size.height, 23, 60))

        self.view.addSubview(signInButton)
        self.view.addSubview(joinButton)
        self.view.addSubview(pageControl)

        signInButton.addTarget(self, action: "signInButtonClicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        joinButton.addTarget(self, action: "joinButtonClicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        pageControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector("changePage:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

        configurePageControl()
        scrollView.delegate = self

        for index in 0...3 {
            frame.size = scrollView.frame.size
            frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
            scrollView.pagingEnabled = true

            let view: UIView = UIView(frame: frame)
            view.backgroundColor = colors[index]
            scrollView.addSubview(view)
        }

        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 4, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)
    }

    func configurePageControl() {
        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = colors.count
        self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
        self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }
```

I put a scrollview on my view controller (using the size class `width: Any` and `height: Any`) and pinned all four sides of the scrollview to the view controller. For some reason each of the views I add to the scrollview are not exactly the same width as the iPhone.

For example when, I tried running it on an iPhone 6 the first view extends past the width of the iPhone. And that happens to the second and third view. I want the first view to be the exact width of the iPhone and the second view to be exactly to the right of the first view and so on. There seems to be some overlapping with the first view going past the width of the iPhone.

Could this be because I am using the size class (width: any and height: any) and I should disable size classes and add a scrollview for each iPhone width?

Can someone help me identify the problem here.

Comment: You should wait for your constraints to calculate and adjust Content Size in `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: Just realized that I was updated the size in viewDidLoad and that's not correct! Thanks for the suggestion, I was able to get it to work!

Comment: CGSizeMake is deprecated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add:

```
scrollView.setNeedsLayout()
scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

at the beginning of the `viewDidLoad()` method.

**Always call these two methods before accessing a view's frame when using Auto Layout, otherwise you'll probably get an incorrect size.**

The problem is that when `viewDidLoad()` is called, your `view` still has a width of `600` (due to your storyboard view controller size of `600x600`).
Your constraints dictate that the scroll view should be the same width as the device, but these constraints are only applied *after* `viewDidLoad()` finishes, when Auto Layout's next scheduled pass is calculated. 
Adding the code above forces Auto Layout to perform a pass, thus giving you the correct frame sizes for subsequent use in your size calculations.

Comment: Thank you so much, It works now! I am still a little confused on how this code fixed it. So during viewDidLoad() the width of the view is 600 (since the storyboard view size is 600x600). But the code above ensures that after viewDidLoad is finished, it will go back and make the sizes correct (not based on the size of the view which was 600 during viewDidLoad because of the storyboard, but now it will resize it based on the size of the iPhone view after viewDidLoad finishes and viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear get called)?

Comment: Yes, you could say these two methods _force_ the system to not wait for `viewWillAppear()` and friends, and apply your constraints immediately. Your constraints are what makes the scroll view take on the size of the screen.

Comment: Ah ok, so at what point do these two methods get called? After viewDidLoad() during the viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear methods?

Comment: Put them at the beginning of `viewDidLoad()`, that way, all the frames will be correct before you use them.

Comment: Ohh, so this way the constraints are applied before I used the size property of the scrollView. Thank you for explaining this concept!

Comment: One really quick thing. I read on the doc that this method `setNeedsLayout` only makes note of the request that you want to adjust the layout of the scrollView's subview but doesn't force and immediate update. So does `layoutIfNeeded` force this immediate update?

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Sorry, but I just had one urging question! If I make the scrollView programmatically in code like this: `scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height))`. Do I still need those two methods you told me to add above? Since I did not add those methods and everything worked fine. Is that because when you add it through code it takes the width of the iPhone screen in `viewDidLoad()` and not the main storyboard which is 600x600.

Comment: In that case you're not using Auto Layout so don't need those methods. `view.frame` always has the correct screen size in `viewDidLoad()`, it's only when using Auto Layout that there's a difference.

Comment: Ohh now this makes complete sense! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Put your scroll view in , set your constraint. Then grab a UIView, put it IN the scroll view, set it as equal width, equal height, and center it (use CTRL + drag to the scroll view, you'll get a small pop up menu)

Then put your content in the UIView you just created... Bam ! also I personally rename my UIView to ContentView, just for sake

Here's a screen to help :

[image]

Now I myself am still having issue with the height, I usually simply use a fixed height for the content view because if I don't it doesn't scroll....

Comment: Just tried this and it worked as well, Thank you for your suggestions!